# Creating Jira Board Filter does not recognize status

Tags: jira, status, issue-tracking, jql

I have a board with a filter to only show status' of "Ready to Release" and "Ready for Release" from two other boards. The query looks like:

```
project in (BRUZ, BDP) AND status in ("Ready to Release", "Ready for Release") ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

I get the following error:
[image: reject]

But, the status clearly exists in project "BDP"
[image]

What gives? Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you use the type ahead for the status name in the Advanced Search?

Comment: Hi @mdoar I'm not sure what you mean by 'type ahead'

Comment: When you start typing in a field and Jira automatically populates the field

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread that. Jira does not  auto-fill any recommendations. Could it be because the BRUZ board is a kanban board? That doesn't seem to make sense because if I don't condition the status, I get all of the BRUZ tasks to result from my filter.

Comment: First of all I would check if the project's workflow truly has the missing status. Because unless you are using Jira simplified workflow, the column name on the board (highlighted on the screenshot) would not necessarily match the workflow status. Check the project workflow in project's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

1. Click on the cog

[image: Click on the cog]

2. Choose Issues from the settings drawer

[image: Choose Issues from the setting drawer]

3. Navigate to Statuses from Issue Attributes

[image: Scroll down and choose Statuses from Issue Attributes]

4. Find "Ready to Release" and right click on edit and open in new tab

[image: Find your status]

5. Get the id of the desired status from the newly opened url

[image: Get the id from the url]

6. Update your JQL and replace the name with the id:

   project in (BRUZ, BDP) AND status in (10011, 10012) ORDER BY Rank ASC

Comment: thanks for your input. I can get BDP's to show, but not BRUZ. There must be something else behind the scenes that is not setup properly: workflow, workflow schema, something. It really shouldn't be this hard!